# PDO connection class prepare error

Tags: php, pdo

I got my connection class in a different folder core/connect.php, it's giving me this error and i dont know how to fix it? sorry for the newb question.

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\register.php on line 11

```
<?php
    function dbconnect(){
        try{
            $username = 'root';
            $password = '';
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lr;", $username, $password);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        } catch(PDOException $e){
            echo 'ERROR',$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

register.php

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username"><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br />
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])){
    require 'core/connect.php';

    $query = dbconnect()->prepare('INSERT INTO `users` (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)');

    $query->bindParam(1, $_POST['username']);
    $query->bindParam(2, $_POST['password']);
    $query->execute();
}
?>
```

Comment: Place `return $pdo;` at the end of your `try{}` block

Comment: You are not returning the `$pdo` handle from your function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
function dbconnect(){
    try{
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lr;", $username, $password);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $pdo;

    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'ERROR',$e->getMessage();
     }
   }
?>
```

Make sure you include connect.php in register.php or are using an autoloader etc.